# How to write custom template tags in Django easily?

Tags: django, templatetags

Writing template tags isn't easy in Django and involves lots of boilerplate code. 
What is the least painful way to do it?

- Are there any libs for that?
- Are there any tricks that doesn't involve third-party apps?
- What is *your* way to do it?

(I will make this post a community wiki once I figure how to do it.)

Comment: Is that a question really? You should rather make a question out of it and provide some solutions as answer.

Comment: You have to flag your own post to get cw and ask a moderator to convert it for you; you can't just mark a post CW any more.

Comment: @gruszczy This seems to be quite practical question which is based on actual problems faced by many web developers who use Django, so basic requirements from the FAQ are met... I'm aware that this question cannot have single correct answer, but that's what community posts are for, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Anton - This is very useful. Please separate the question and answer, however. The answer that you provide should really be posted as an answer. Otherwise, Stack Overflow will see this as an 'unanswered question' I would do this for you, but then I'd get credit for your answer.

Comment: @Anton: I wasn't clear enough. I don't mean, that this is a wrong question for Stack Overflow. Rather I wanted to point, that it is not the right format. In question, you should ask. If you have your own answer already, answer your own question.

Comment: @Tim Post, @gruszczy: Thanks for clarification! I moved the de-facto answer out of question. (I thought it's common practice for wiki-like questions to collect and organize info from provided answers and other sources in the question body for easier access.)

Comment: Turns out I can convert an _answer_ to community wiki. Stupid me =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

There are some libs for that:

- [**django-templatetag-sugar**](http://github.com/alex/django-templatetag-sugar/)

  Used it before. Makes everythings simpler, but I couldn't figure how to handle lots of optional arguments with it.

  Usage example::

  ```
  ''' {% example_tag for val as asvar %} '''

  @tag(register, [
      Constant("for"), Variable(),
      Optional([Constant("as"), Name()]),
      ])
  def example_tag(context, val, asvar=None):
      if asvar:
          context[asvar] = val
          return ""
      else:
          return val
  ```
- [**django-tagcon**](https://github.com/tomxtobin/django-tagcon), abandoned by original author
- [**django-ttag**](http://github.com/lincolnloop/django-ttag), fork of **django-tagcon**

  These two look promising because of class-based approach and keyword arguments support (like `{% output limit=some_limit|default:1 offset=profile.offset %}`)

  Example usage::

  ```
  class Welcome(ttag.Tag):
      ''' {% welcome current_user fallback "Hello, anonymous." %} '''
      user = ttag.Arg(positional=True)
      fallback = ttag.Arg(default='Hi!')

      def output(self, data)
          name = data['user'].get_full_name()
          if name:
              return 'Hi, %s!' % name
          return data['fallback']
  ```

---

Answer (score 6):

Try django-classy-tags https://github.com/ojii/django-classy-tags

Answer (score 0):

I use the fancy_tag decorator: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancy_tag

Very simple and powerful and it comes with good documentation.

Gets rid of all that boilerplate when you just want to assign the output of a template tag to a context variable. Also handles (variable length) arguments and keyword arguments.

Much easier to use than for example django-templatetag-sugar.

I haven't really needed anything else apart from the built in inclusion tag decorator.